# Spring packages problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estoy levantando por primera vez una aplicacion en Spring , pero cuando quiero correrla , me tira un error de que no encuentra unos beans o algo relacionado con eso.
El proyecto esta separado en diferentes paquetes , dependiendo de la capa que sea (servicio , modelo , dao , etc).
Cuando busque el error , me dijiero que la solución podia ser scanBasePackages , con los paquetes adentro  , pero esto no me funcionó y el error sigue siendo el mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controlador

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class PublicController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService aService;


    @GetMapping("/persona")
    public void savePersona(){
        aService.save();
    }

}
```

Servicio

```java
@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDao aDao;


    public void save() {
        Account x = new Account();
        x.setUsername("rodrigo");
        x.setPassword("12345");
        aDao.save(x);
    }

}
```

Dao

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountDao extends JpaRepository<Account , Integer>{



}
```

y el error que tira es el siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas definir explícitamente el component-scan si utilizas la anotación `@SpringBootApplication`. Esta activa el escaneo del paquete que contiene la clase anotada y recursivamente todos sus subpaquetes.

El problema que yo veo es que estás definiendo manualente las dependencias que "supuestamente" necesitas para trabajar con JPA/Hibernate en Spring Boot.

En este sentido te recomiendo que elimines todas estas dependencias y solo uses el starter para jpa.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Y que elimines la definición del atributo `scanBasePackages` de la anotación `@SpringBootApplication` (esto porque no es necesario, pero igual funciona como está, solo que redundante). También elimina la anotación `@ComponentScan`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FutbitoApplication {
    // tu código
}
```

Con esto debe ser suficiente para que funcione.